# WebGL heightmap using vertex shader, using 32 bits instead of 8 bits

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, vertex-shader, heightmap

I'm using the following vertex shader (courtesy http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Heightmap-Textures.html) to generate terrain from a grayscale height map:

```
uniform sampler2D bumpTexture;
uniform float bumpScale;

varying float vAmount;
varying vec2 vUV;

void main()
{
  vUV = uv;
  vec4 bumpData = texture2D( bumpTexture, uv );

  vAmount = bumpData.r; // assuming map is grayscale it doesn't matter if you use r, g, or b.

  // move the position along the normal
  vec3 newPosition = position + normal * bumpScale * vAmount;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0);
}
```

I'd like to have 32-bits of resolution, and have generated a heightmap that encodes heights as RGBA.  I have no idea how to go about changing the shader code to accommodate this.  Any direction or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bumpData.r`, `.g`, `.b` and `.a` are all quantities in the range [0.0, 1.0] equivalent to the original byte values divided by `255.0`.

So depending on your endianness, a naive conversion back to the original int might be:

```
(bumpData.r * 255.0) + 
(bumpdata.g * 255.0 * 256.0) + 
(bumpData.b * 255.0 * 256.0 * 256.0) + 
(bumpData.a * 255.0 * 256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0)
```

So that's the same as a dot product with the vector `(255.0, 65280.0, 16711680.0, 4278190080.0)`, which is likely to be the much more efficient way to implement it.

Comment: One should note that this approach will produce atrifacts when used with something else than `GL_NEAREST` filtering,as the channels are independently filtered. One could naively assume that this is not a problem by multiplying the mix factors into above formula, but that is ignoring the wraparound.   E.g., if one texel has the (normalized) color value (1,0,1,0)  (representing 16711935) and the neighbor has (0,1,0,0) (representing 256), the interpolation in the middle between them might yield (0.5, 0,5, 0,5,0), which represents 8388607.5, while the correct value would be 8356095.5.

Comment: Hey Tommy, thanks for the answer.  I'm using this solution (the dot product  solution, specifically) and am still running into issues with the problem as a whole.  I've created a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663001/implementing-a-32-bit-heightmap-vertex-shader-in-threejs) since it's broader in nature.  If you could take a look at it and offer additional help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

With threejs

```
const generateHeightTexture = (width) => {
  // let max_texture_width = RENDERER.capabilities.maxTextureSize;
  let pixels = new Float32Array(width * width)
  pixels.fill(0, 0, pixels.length);
  let texture = new THREE.DataTexture(pixels, width, width, THREE.AlphaFormat, THREE.FloatType);

  texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
  // texture.anisotropy = RENDERER.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  console.log('Built Physical Texture:', width, 'x', width)
  return texture;
}
```